# How many blocks have no unspent transaction outputs?

Tags: transactions, block

I can't seem to find statistics anywhere on how many blocks have no UTXOs, or what the distribution of UTXOs are in blocks over time, or anything like that. If you could point me in the direction of something along these lines that'd be great!

Answer (score 3):

The page [Bitcoin UTXO Stats](https://utxo-stats.com/) has a visualization of the number of UTXOs in each block (image with orange pixels).

Each pixel of the image represents a block, and the color of the pixel indicates how many UTXOs can be found in that block (black pixels indicate a few UTXOs whereas orange ones indicate lots of UTXOs). Hovering over a pixel shows data about the specific block and clicking on a pixel redirects to the block page on [blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info).

Answer (score -1):

> I can't seem to find statistics anywhere on how many blocks have no UTXOs

what is the sense to counting it?

> or what the distribution of UTXOs are in blocks over time, or anything like that

http://statoshi.info/dashboard/db/unspent-transaction-output-set

https://p2sh.info/dashboard/db/utxo-repartition?orgId=1

Comment: Thanks for the links, very helpful! The reason I wanted to know how many blocks have no UTXOs is I thought possibly blocks with no UTXOs could have their tx vector pruned and save space on the blockchain, since they were no longer relevant for calculating UTXOs.

Comment: As far as I know the UTXO set does not contain information about blocks at all. You may prune all block database and leave only UTXO set. The reason  for keeping blocks on your disk is only for distributing the database to a new nodes